# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined With Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm trying to get ajax to work with a ajax tutorial on Tutorialspoint. But even after I include 'jquery-rails' gem into gemfile and use 'bundle install' command I still get "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error in my browser console, and ajax function doesn't work.
I still have to refresh the page to see the result.
(I generated the codes with scaffold)

my index.view.erb

```
<h1>Ponies</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @ponies.each do |pony| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= pony.name %></td>
        <td><%= pony.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', pony %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pony_path(pony) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', pony, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true, :class => 'delete_pony' %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Pony', new_pony_path %>
```

my destroy.js.erb

```
$('.delete_pony').bind('ajax:success', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
});
```

my ponies_controller.rb

```
...

def destroy
    @pony.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to ponies_url, notice: 'Pony was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js { render :layout => false }
    end
  end

...
```

gemfile

```
...

gem 'jquery-rails'

...
```

browser console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
    at processResponse (rails-ujs.js:283)
    at rails-ujs.js:196
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.js:264)
```

application.js

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")


// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: `$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {` you have to write js code inside this function ...

Comment: I still get the same result. The problem was the dollar sign '$' i think. Somehow rails doesn't let me use jquery

Comment: `jQuery.fn.jquery` check jquery version in your console...

Comment: I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` error

Comment: Jquery is not loaded to the rails application

Comment: did you add `//= require jquery` in your application.js ???

Comment: I did actually, in an attempt to make this work. both `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs`

Comment: which is your rails version???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202240/discussion-between-ngancun-and-abhishek-aravindan).

Comment: Use the webpacker instructions https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs#installation-using-rails-and-webpacker, personally, I would use rails-ujs and not jquery_ujs for unobtrusive javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using rails 6. Add following code to your `config/webpack/environment.js` file.

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

For more information visit: [introducing-jQuery-in-rails-6-using-webpacker](https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/introducing-jquery-in-rails-6-using-webpacker)

Answer (score 3):

Along with updating your environment file, one thing that I did that was a quick fix was to add this to your application.js file in the javascript folder.

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jquery = jquery;
```